# Install wasJmsClient-2.0 feature in Liberty Profile 8.5.5.2

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty

I am using WAS LP 8.5.5.2 with Oracle Java 1.7 on windows 7 Machine. I want to use **wasJmsClient-2.0** feature in  in my Application. I ran the "productInfo featureInfo" command but its output doesn't display feature **wasJmsClient-2.0**. How can I install this feature into the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wasJmsClient-2.0 feature isn't available for 8.5.5.2, it is only currently available as a beta. It will be available on June 26th 2015, but that'll only install on top of 8.5.5.6 so you will need to upgrade.

There is a wasJmsClient-1.1 feature which is available for 8.5.5.2. If you need this on 8.5.5.2 then you can get it by downloading the [wlp-extended-8.5.5.2.jar](http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/downloadFixes?parent=ibm%7EWebSphere&product=ibm/WebSphere/WebSphere%20Application%20Server&release=8.5.5.2&platform=All&function=fixId&fixids=8552-wlp-extended-archive&includeRequisites=1&includeSupersedes=0&downloadMethod=http) which can be downloaded from fix central. Otherwise I'd suggest upgrading to the latest from fix central, or [wasdev.net](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/liberty-profile-using-non-eclipse-environments/) and running:

```
bin/featureManager install wasJmsClient-1.1
```